How do I retrieve data from azure devops board into excel only in view only mode
How do I retrieve data from azure devops board query into excel where I can modify the data in excel but it shouldn't publish the modified data back into azure board. When I click on refresh button in excel it should refresh the data but even after modification in excel it shouldn't update data backwards. Basically, only fetch should work and not push.
I tried to install Visual studio 2022 and azure devops integration tool where I was able to fetch data from azure board but it has publish button in tool bar. Expectation is to restrict the person from updating bulk data.
Is there any other way like creating scripts or through power BI we can achieve this? Thanks in advance

As long as a user in the Azure DevOps project has the "Edit work items" permission in an area path, this user can update work items assigned to that area path both on the web UI of Azure DevOps and in the exported Excel.
If you want a user cannot update work items via the exported Excel, you need to set the "Edit work items" permission to "Deny" for this user. However, this user also will not be able to update work items on the web UI of Azure DevOps and via other ways.
It is not possible to set a user can update work items on the web UI of Azure DevOps while cannot do this in the exported Excel.
